XAI LIME Feature Importance Value
The part in the red rectangle is the feature importance for a prediction. I would like to know where the value of the feature importance comes from. Is there any specific math equation or a specific function in the LIME library?
This is the library from github
https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/tree/master/lime
LIME explanation
I've read the paper, you can find it here
https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04938
I don't quite understand which math equation that calculate the feature importance value
